# How can I put this div scroll using display: table?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxpbqE)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="scrollable">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#wrap{
  display:table;  //Here is the problem
  background: #F7F7F7;
}
#scrollable{
  overflow-y:auto;
}
table{
  min-width:1000px;
}
```

If you get "display: table" when everything works properly but I do not want to give up on him.

I want to make scrolling table.

It can do this?practicaly I want to div `#scrollable` have scroll but without canceling the `"display: table"`

Can you help me find a solution to this problem please?

Thank you!

Comment: you want scroll for table or for #scrollable?

Comment: can you explain more about your question ?.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

Mention some height for #scrollable

like

```
#scrollable{
  overflow-y:auto;
height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS :

```
table{
  min-width:1000px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
   height:50px;
   display:block;
}
```

For Horizontal :

```
table{
  width:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
   display:block;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ktyLsLa4/)

Comment: in that demo link replace that table css by my new table css

Comment: you clear links? Plaste put the complete example for horizontal scroll

Comment: Now check the answer , with Demo Link

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the wrapper for controlling the overflow and apply display:table only to your table element.

Example below.

```css
#wrap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  overflow-y: scroll; // make the wrapper scrollable
  overflow-x: none;
}

#table {
  display: table; // apply table layout
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="scrollable">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but I want to be horizontal scrolling div and the "wrap" have "display: table"
I can not change those two things